# How to do na_values when creating pandas dataframe from Google BigQuery

Tags: pandas, google-bigquery, google-colaboratory

I had used `pd.read_csv(my_csv, na_values=['N/A', '--'])` such that string 'N/A' and '--' get interpreted as NULL, NaN, etc.

But if I used BigQuery client, I couldn't figure how to achieve the same feat. I read the quick help from .to_dataframe() which "Return a pandas DataFrame from a QueryJob" but it didn't seem to take in any extra argument.

Is this possible? Or I have to do my own custom post-processing to track missing values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve same from below:

```
dataFrame.applymap(lambda x: np.nan if x in ['N/A', '--'] else x)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running some query before getting its results in to the dataframe, you can easily do it on the BigQuery side without worrying about filtering your results on the client side.

Something like `IF(column in ('N\A', '--'), null, column) as column` should do the job for you.